# Google Protocol Buffers (protobuf) in Python3 - trouble with ParseFromString (encoding?)

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding, protocol-buffers

I've got Google Protocol buffers 80% working in Python3. My .proto file works, I'm encoding data, life is almost good.
The problem is that I can't ParseFromString the result of SerializeToString.
When I print SerializeToString it looks like what I'd expect, a fairly compact binary representation (preceded by b').

My guess is that perhaps this is a difference in the way Python2 and Python3 handle strings. The putput of SerializeToString is Bytes, not a string.

Printed output of SerializeToString (Python type is ):

```
b'\x10\xd7\xeb\x8e\xcd\x04\x1a\x0cnamegoeshere2@\x08\x80\xf8\xde\xc3\x9f\xb0\x81\x89\x14\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80d\xc0\x19\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0m@!\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80R\xc0)\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x\xb7\xc01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x95@9\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\xb2@'
```

result of ParseFromString(message):

```
None
```

No error is provided...

So - my best guess is that all I need to do is .decode() the bytes object generated, the problem is that I have no clue what the encoding is. I've tried UTF-8, -16, Latin-1, and a few others without success. My Google-Fu is strong but I haven't found anything on this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show the code which calls ParseFromString

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`ParseFromString` is a method -- it does not return anything, but rather fills in `self` with the parsed content. Use it like:

```
message = MyMessageType()
message.ParseFromString(data)
print(message.some_field)
```

Comment: Is there a way to check if `ParseFromString` was successful or not? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: @pooya13 I believe it will throw an exception if the message is completely unparseable. However, keep in mind that usually, any valid Protobuf can successfully parse as _any_ type, because the underlying format does not contain type information. So you won't necessarily get a parse error if you parse as the wrong type -- you'll just get garbage content.

Comment: what if we have large string data how can one handle such scenario, thanks in advance.