# Check if the response of a get api is a proto object

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, protocol-buffers

I fetch a `proto` object from an api , is there anyway I can validate that the `response` is a `proto` object.

One thing which I did was check `content-type` as mentioned in the [json counterpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37121301/how-to-check-if-the-response-of-a-fetch-is-a-json-object-in-javascript) of this question. But the answer goes on further to validate `json` using `JSON.parse`

The content-type of a proto file comes out to be `application/octet-stream` ( `protobuf` can have this `content-type` , check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505408/what-is-the-correct-protobuf-content-type) )

Is there **any other check** I should do to validate `response` is a `proto` object ?

**EDIT** : `Proto` means 
**Protocol Buffers** : https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers

Comment: Are you referring to the __proto__ in javascript, or to a python class named proto?

Comment: Protocol Buffers : https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Comment: Why not just try to `ParseFromString(response)`? If doesn't raise a `DecodeError` exception, then it passes validation.

Comment: Going by the documentation , this could be a good check . Let me try this !

Comment: @cr3 Thanks for the comment. But this requires to know the messageType of the proto file . Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816761/google-protocol-buffers-protobuf-in-python3-trouble-with-parsefromstring-en) for usage of `ParseFromString(response)`. Can there be a more general answer ?

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava for a given endpoint, you should expect a single message type. If your endpoint can receive a handful of message types, you could loop over each type until one doesn't raise a `DecodeError` exception. If this part of the code can't determine any of the message types for some reason, then it might be acceptable to assume protobuf when the content-type is `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: @cr3 I totally get your point , my case was that I have a single framework setup for parsing response for all api's in my project , and each api has different messageType in that case i guess checking only `content-type` would be helpful !

Answer (score 0):

The Content-Type representation header is used to indicate the original media type of the resource (prior to any content encoding applied for sending). Meanwhile, protobuf is serialization/de-serialization schema/library. So they are different.