# How deserialize protocol buffers from http response use python

Tags: python-3.x, protocol-buffers

I want to deserialize an API response to a python object whose content-type is protobuf, I use the ParseFromString method to parse the HTTP response, but only get a number 23, print the response content directly is `b'\n\x08Hi,py-pb'`. So, how do I deserialize the HTTP response to the python object?

proto file content:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package greet;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

python code:

```py
# _*_ coding: utf8 _*_

from google.protobuf.json_format import ParseDict, MessageToJson
from protos.greet_pb2 import HelloRequest, HelloReply
import httpx
import asyncio


async def send_req():
    req = {'name': 'py-pb'}
    msg = ParseDict(req, HelloRequest())
    print(msg)
    print(type(msg))
    print(msg.SerializeToString())

    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        resp = await client.post('http://localhost:5044/greet/Greeter/SayHello', data=msg.SerializeToString(),
                           headers={'Accept': 'application/protobuf', 'Content-Type': 'application/protobuf'})
        print('=========response=========')
        # print(resp.stream)
        # print(resp.content)
        # print(resp.text)
        resp_msg = HelloReply().ParseFromString(resp.content)
        # resp_msg = HelloReply().SerializeToString(resp.content)
        print(resp_msg)

asyncio.run(send_req())
```

Versions:
Python - 3.10.5
google.protobuf - 4.21.2

Related answer:

```
ParseFromString is a method -- it does not return anything, but rather fills in self with the parsed content.
```

Reference:
[Google Protocol Buffers (protobuf) in Python3 - trouble with ParseFromString (encoding?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816761/google-protocol-buffers-protobuf-in-python3-trouble-with-parsefromstring-en)

Answer (score 0):

[`ParseFromString`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#reading-a-message) is an instance method. So you want, e.g.:

```py
hello_reply = HelloReply()
hello_reply.ParseFromString(resp.content)
```

The docs include an example using [`ParseFromString`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#reading-a-message).

Here's a repro:

```py
from google.protobuf.json_format import ParseDict, MessageToJson
from greet_pb2 import HelloRequest, HelloReply


rqst = {'name': 'py-pb'}
msg = ParseDict(rqst, HelloRequest())
tx = msg.SerializeToString()
print(tx)
print(tx.hex())

resp = HelloReply()
resp.ParseFromString(tx)
print(resp)
```

Yields:

```
b'\n\x05py-pb'
0a0570792d7062
message: "py-pb"
```

You can take the binary as hex and plug it into [`protogen`](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode) to decode it.

```
Field #1: 0A String Length = 5, Hex = 05, UTF8 = "py-pb"
```

Comment: Thanks, but this method does not work for me. I need to deserialize the data from the HTTP response.

Comment: Yes, it does. You  need to incorporate my solution into your code. You must instantiate an `HelloReply` object and use `ParseFromString` against the instance. You're trying to `HelloReply().ParseFromString()` and that won't work. You probably want to replace `tx` with `resp.content` when you add `httpx`.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work. I use python3.10.5 & google.protobuf4.21.2